# The meaning of 切る on the end of verbs

Tags: grammar, suffixes

Is there a general meaning for `切る` on the end of verbs?

I think it might have to do with "completely doing" something. If that's the case, how does `～切る` on the end of verbs differ from `～てしまう`, for example how do `成り切った` and `なってしまった` "turned completely into" differ in meaning?

Additionally:

- How does the meaning of `支え切れなくなる` differ from `支えられなくなる` "become unable to support"? Can `支え切れなくなる` mean "will go past the point of being able to support"?
- How does `疲れ切った` differ from `疲れた` "exhausted"? 
  Does `完全に疲れた` "completely exhausted" have a similar meaning to `疲れ切った`?
- What is the relationship between `割り切る` and `割る`?

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes. The meaning of `きる` common to those examples is to `complete doing ...`.
2. `てしまう` does not necessarily mean `complete doing ...`. So they are different.

Comment: しまう is explained in the dictionary as "to finish; to close; to do something completely". Is there another meaning that is not about "finish" ?

Comment: I suppose it's due to "complete" having two meanings. "to the full extent of" and "finish doing". "completely exhausted" = "to the full extent of being exhausted" ≠ "to finish being exhausted".

Comment: @Flaw It depends on the aspectuality of the predicate. For example, `怖いものを見てしまった` does not mean "complete seeing", "seeing" in this in example is done in an instance.

Comment: @Flaw Don't learn grammar from EDICT.

Answer (score 2):

Well, ～しまう kinda means that you ended up doing something, or that something happened that you don't feel so great about.  I often use it at work to say something like そうすると、難しくなってしまう which gives the nuance that it's regrettable, but it will ended up being hard if you do it like that.

～きる means do something thoroughly.  A common example is 本当にそう言い切れるのか？  Can you REALLY say that (and mean it/be sure about it)?  Another one would be 使い切る which means use something until it's gone/used up.